# iCheck checkbox select all , and refresh data table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox, icheck

I'm using iCheck for checkbox style in bootstrap , but I'm having some issues I can't check/uncheck all ,, and  dotn  work refresh data table in time, need to refresh page , or page refreshed itslef.

and checkbox in premium or public  , when I select it will stay checked and after i will reload page ,,

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table">
        <!-- Start Header -->
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    <label class="checkbox checkbox-inline">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="file_id" value="0">
                    </label>
                </th>
                <th>Text Name</th>
                <th>Sixe Date</th>
                <th>Created Date</th>
                <th>Something</th>
                <th>Premium</i>
                </th>
                <th>Public</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">
                    <label class="checkbox checkbox-inline">
                        <input id="check" type="checkbox" name="file_id">
                    </label>
                </th>
                <td>Something</td>
                <td>Size</td>
                <td>Date</td>
                <td>Name</td>
                <td>
                    <label class="checkbox checkbox-inline">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="file_premium_only" </label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <label class="checkbox checkbox-inline">
                        <input type="checkbox">
                    </label>
                </td>
          </tr> 
          <tr>
                <th scope="row">
                    <label class="checkbox checkbox-inline">
                        <input id="check" type="checkbox" name="file_id">
                    </label>
                </th>
                <td>Something</td>
                <td>Size</td>
                <td>Date</td>
                <td>Name</td>
                <td>
                    <label class="checkbox checkbox-inline">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="file_premium_only" </label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <label class="checkbox checkbox-inline">
                        <input type="checkbox">
                    </label>
                </td>
          </tr> 
    </table>
</div>
<!-- /.table-responsive -->
```

here u can see codepen example:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QjvomM

Answer (score 3):

You can use `ifToggled` iCheck event and if checked/unchecked act accordingly in the other rows using `check` and `uncheck` methods.

Ref:

https://github.com/fronteed/iCheck#callbacks

https://github.com/fronteed/iCheck#methods

Side note: I set a specific class `all` for the select all check and a specific class each row check `selector`, avoid mutiple id values.

Code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

    $('input').iCheck({
        checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_flat-pink',
        radioClass: 'iradio_flat-pink'
    });

    $('input.all').on('ifToggled', function (event) {
        var chkToggle;
        $(this).is(':checked') ? chkToggle = "check" : chkToggle = "uncheck";
        $('input.selector:not(.all)').iCheck(chkToggle);
    });

});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/estL6xrv/

Answer (score 2):

If I understand the question correctly you wish to give your page the functionality to check/uncheck a collection of iCheck checkboxes at the same time?

I achieved something similar to this with the following jQuery function..

```
function ToggleCheckboxes() {

    var flag = $('#togglebox').is(':checked')

    $("[name='PrintCheck']").each(function () {
        if (flag == true) {
            $(this).iCheck('check');                
        } else {
            $(this).iCheck('uncheck');                
        }
    });
```

}

This function was assigned to the onchange of the top checkbox. This would then find all of the checkboxes with the name 'PrintCheck' and either check or uncheck.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="togglebox" onchange="ToggleCheckboxes();">
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I try but It dosn't work ,,  I want after check first checkbox in table thet can check all other  ,, like that http://issues.wenzhixin.net.cn/bootstrap-table/ and sorry for my bad english

Comment: So using my approach what you should be able to do is...

1) set the 'onclick' function of the top checkbox to ToggleCheckboxes (from my answer)

2) Set the 'name' attribute of all the checkboxes in the list to anything you like.

3) Replace "[name='PrintCheck'] with "[name=YOURNAME']"

If this still does not work then you should check the browser console for any JS errors above that would prevent it from working

Comment: Sorry a correction, set the checkbox 'onchange' NOT 'onclick' to ToggleCheckboxes

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/jymy5qox/3/ .....Here is a quick JSFiddle I wrote that will hopefully help!